# Javascript regex to add to every character of a string a backslash

Tags: javascript, regex

So as the title says I'd like to add to every character of a string a backslash, whether the string has special characters or not. The string should not be considered 'safe'

```
eg: 
let str = 'dj%^3&something';
str = str.replace(x, y);
// str = '\d\j\%\^\3\&\s\o\m\e\t\h\i\n\g'
```

Comment: First of all, `let str = '\dj%^3&something';` = `let str = 'dj%^3&something';` - there is no literal backslash in your string literal. Then, what doesn't work for you? Show the code that you have problems with.

Comment: That was an example, indeed there would be no backslash there, let me edit it. The string would come from user input, thats just it.

Comment: Ok, but what is the *programming issue* you are having? The *task* is clear.

Comment: The task is easy, as the answer shows below, but I want to be sure its 'safe' to use, as in it can't be exploited.

Comment: safe for what?  do you want to display it on a web page?

Comment: Yes, thats the intent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to display a string safely, you should just do:

```
let str = 'dj%^3&something';
let node = document.createTextNode(str);
let dest = document.querySelector('.whatever');
dest.appendChild(node);
```

And then you are guaranteed that it will be treated as text, and won't be able to execute a script or anything.

For example: https://jsfiddle.net/s6udj03L/1/

Answer (score 3):

You could capture every character in the string with `(.)` and use `\\$1` as replacement, I'm not an expert but basically `\\` will render to `\` and `$1` will render to whatever `(.)` captures.

HIH

**EDIT**

please refer to [Wiktor Stribiżew's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49885001/javascript-regex-to-add-to-every-character-of-a-string-a-bashlash/49885094#comment86786244_49885094) for an alternative which will require less coding. Changes as follows:

`str = str.replace(/(.)/g, '\\$1');` for `str = str.replace(/./g, '\\$&');`

Also, for future reference I strongly advice you to visit regexr.com when it comes to regular expressions, it's helped ME a lot

```js
let str = 'dj%^3&something';
str = str.replace(/(.)/g, '\\$1');

console.log(str);
```

Comment: Why use outer capturing parentheses when you can refer to the whole match in the replacement string with `$&`? Besides,  `.` does not match *every* char, it does not match linebreak chars.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew as I said, not an expert, I just tested your comment and it works great, thank you.

Comment: You may remove the answer as it does not answer the actual question. OP does not need to escape all chars in the string.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string to an array, add a `\` to each element to the array, then joint the array back to the string that you wanted.

```js
var str = 'dj%^3&something';
var split = str.split(""); // split string into array
for (var i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
    split[i] = '\\' + split[i]; // add backslash to each element in array
}
var joint = split.join('') // joint array to string

console.log(joint);
```

Comment: why wouldn't you just do `'\\' + str.split("").join('\\');`?

Comment: true, that would be another solution to the question too.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about creating a new `string` and don't really have to use a regex, why not just iterate over the existing one and place a `\` before each `char`. Notice to you have to put `\\` to escape the first `\`.

To consider it safe, you have to encode it somehow. You could replace typical 'non-safe' characters like in the `encode()` function below. Notice how `&` get's replaced by `&amp;`

```js
let str = 'dj%^3&something';
let out = "";
for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  out += ("\\" + str[i]);
}
console.log(out);
console.log(encode(out));

function encode(string) {
    return String(string).replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;').replace(/"/g, '&quot;');
}
```